# Getting MX Records in a C program

Tags: c, dns, mx-record

I need to find out the mx records bound to a domain for an SMTP server.
The thing is, I can't use any library except the system ones (Linux and Windows).

There's very little documentation around the web around that...

Right now, I have the domain name with which I need to talk, as a string.
And what I need is the MX Record from this name, just as I would get them using the "nslookup -type=mx domain.com" command. Except that I need to get those records by myself, and in a way that will work running either Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux systems you should have `libresolv` available as part of `glibc`.

Take a look at the man page for the `res_query` function.

Comment: Exactly what I need ! And it seems it's on Windows to (not sure about this one though, still investigating) ! Thanks !